# How to calculate total of all rows and display as column?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

For E.g. I have a table as below:

```
Fruit        |      Count  
=================================    
Apples       |       3              
Oranges      |       4  
Pineapple    |       3
Pear         |       5
```

I want to select from this table, find total count of fruits (which in this example would be 15) and display that total in the select query output. (along each row). Output sample:

```
Fruit          Count         Total   
-----------|------------|-------------      
Apples     |     3      |    15    
Oranges    |     4      |    15
Pineapple  |     3      |    15
Pear       |     5      |    15
```

I have tried the query below and it works:

```
select Fruit, Count, (select sum(count) from FruitTable) from FruitTable;
```

But I do not want to write a sub query. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Are you actually starting from a table that looks like that, or from a query that calculates the basic count for each fruit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Analytic functions come in handy here:

```
SELECT
    Fruit,
    Count,
    SUM(Count) OVER () Total
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Wouldn't a cross join would be better in performance? I guess the analytic would check the SUM for each row

Comment: @bradbury9 No, a `CROSS JOIN` will need two table/index scans (one for each side of the join) but an analytic function will only need one.

Comment: @MT0 Good interview question.

Comment: Should have checked the execution plan, thanks for the correction

Comment: Just checked agains a 17k record table and `select Id, total.Amount from TableName p cross join (select count('X') as Amount from TableName) total` is slightly better than `select Id, count('X') over() as Amount from TableName p`. Not sure if it is significant, but the execution plan looks better to me with a cross join.